# Multiple processes are working smoothly so why do we need web worker in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused with the use and advantages of web workers. I was able to create two buttons that start two counters and the values of both counters are displayed in the screen. Also I created ball movement to create animation. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
    @keyframes ballmovement {
        0% {
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        33% {
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 160px;
        }

        66% {
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        100% {
            margin-left: 300px;
            margin-top: 160px;
            background-color: purple;
        }
    }

    .animate {
        animation-name: ballmovement;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: 40;
        animation-direction: alternate;
    }

    #ball {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-color: black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    #container {
        float: left; 
        height: 500px; 
        width: 50%; 
    }
    #bus {
    display: inline; 
    }
</style>
<script> 
    function startWorker1() {
        i = 0; 
        timedCount1();
    }

    function startWorker2() {
        j = 0;
        timedCount2();
    }

    function timedCount1() {
        i = i + 1;
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = i;
        setTimeout("timedCount1()", 500);
    }
    function timedCount2() {
        j = j + 1;
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = j;
        setTimeout("timedCount2()", 500);
    }

function stopWorker() {
    w.terminate(); 
    w = undefined; 
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="ball" class="animate"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bus">
    <button onclick="startWorker1()">Start Worker 1</button> 
    <button onclick="startWorker2()">Start Worker 2</button> 
    <button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    <div id="result2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code worked really smoothly and no process disturbed the other process.

Since I created in the code above three processes that are working in parallel, why do we need web workers?

Comment: To do heavier computations that are not UI related?

Comment: web workers are useful for code that requires web workers

Comment: You're using asynchronous setTimeout functions. There aren't actually any web workers in your code. Web workers operate in the background and do not have access to the DOM. Read more - [Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @ThisClark: That's his point: his code is smooth, and he didn't use web workers, so what's the point of web workers.

Comment: You captured the essence of what I wanted to say in your answer, *"There are no long-running functions in your code, so you can't see the effect."*

Comment: @ThisClark Consider this scenario. I have a button when clicked a javascript infinite loop will be implemented. Do you think this will cause the page to freeze?

Comment: If the infinite loop is on the main thread, yes the page will freeze. If you offload it to a web worker, no the page will not freeze.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and the page froze. But why it doesn't freeze when I implement infinite loop that always calculate just like the one above? Is it like the empty infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All non-Web-worker JavaScript in a single document is single-threaded: it can only use one processor on the machine, and any significant uninterrupted processing will hog up the tab, preventing not only other JavaScript processes (*), but even display updating, even GIF animations. There are no long-running functions in your code, so you can't see the effect.

For example, try this:

```js
function naiveFibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= 2) return 1;
  return naiveFibonacci(n - 1) + naiveFibonacci(n - 2);
}
s.addEventListener('click', evt => r.textContent = `is ${naiveFibonacci(parseInt(n.value))}`);
```

```html
Naive Fibonacci of: <input id="n"><button id="s">Go</button> <span id="r"></span>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Ajax-loader.gif">
```

On my computer, `naiveFibonacci(42)` takes about 2 seconds. Don't go too high, or your browser pane will crash; if you go too low, you just might miss the effect. You will notice that the spinning GIF will pause while the calculation is being made.

Changing uninterrupted calculations to timeouts so that they can give the browser some breathing space is, while trivial in this case, not trivial in a general case, so while it was necessary before Web workers, it's not ideal. Offloading long calculations to Web workers is the scenario they are designed for.

---

*) general "processes" as in "stuff that needs to be going on", not a technical "processes" as in "instances of computer program being executed"

Comment: It's a little odd to say "all Javascript is single-threaded" in a question that is talking about webWorkers that are clearly additional threads of execution.  You could stand to improve that wording.  There are multiple threads.  You just have to live within the limitations of a webWorker in order to have additional threads.

Comment: Then why my code in my question body did not freeze the home page? Is the calculation of the counter considered long running because it will continue counting?

Comment: Incrementing a variable, changing text in DOM and scheduling a new task takes a very small amount of time. No, those are not long-running. You have no single task that continues running: you have a large number of very short tasks, each of which exits almost immediately. This is what plain JavaScript handles very well, no need for Web workers.

Comment: march 2018 - Chrome v.65 - GIF is not freezing. you sir, are a lier. +1.